# Spring Security: Custom RequestEntityConverter with multiple clients

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I was working on getting a client credential flow with Auth0 to work using Spring Security 5.4.1. I created a little demo application for reference: https://github.com/mathias-ewald/spring-security-auth0-clientcredentials-demo

Everything works fine, but I was wondering how to handle multiple OAuth2 clients. As far as I understand, the configuration made in [OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig](https://github.com/mathias-ewald/spring-security-auth0-clientcredentials-demo/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/demo/OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig.java) is valid for all client credential flows to any provider, correct?

What if I have another provider and don't want to convert RequestEntity in the same way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's usually no perfect answer for multi-tenancy since a lot depends on how early in the request you want to fork the behavior.

In Spring Security's OAuth 2.0 Client support, the `ClientRegistration` is the tenant, and that tenant information is available in most of the client APIs.

For example, your `Auth0RequestEntityConverter` could have different behavior based on the `ClientRegistration` in the request:

```java
public RequestEntity<?> convert(
        OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantRequest request) {
    ClientRegistration client = request.getClientRegistration();
    if (client ...) {
    } else if (client ...) {
    } ...
}
```

Or, if you need to configure more things than the request entity converter, you could instead fork the behavior earlier by constructing a `OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager` for each provider:

```java
public class ClientsOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager implements OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager {
    private final Map<String, OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager> managers;

    // ...

    public OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorize(OAuth2AuthorizeRequest request) {
        String clientRegistrationId = request.getClientRegistrationId();
        return this.managers.get(clientRegistrationId).authorize(request);
    }
}
```